# Implementing d3 append react component

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

Is there any way to implement something like this:

```
d3.select("any-tag").append(<ReactComponent/>)
```

Comment: You can try this library https://github.com/hshoff/vx

Comment: This may not be the best design. Depending on what you're trying to do, it's probably not necessary to use D3 to manipulate React components since React can do a lot of that on its own.

Comment: Yes, I've removed the d3 from the project.